# Why are fast passenger airplanes no longer produced?

Tags: airliner, plane-construction

Concorde was a fast aircraft, but no comparable aircraft is designed today by manufacturers.

What are the main reasons for manufacturers to prefer larger planes carrying more passengers rather than planes flying faster with a less passengers?